# Look who's talking?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Can you tell me who's talking...

[image: colors]

...and what is she trying to tell us?

Hint 1:

> No maths needed

Hint 2:

> After the "dirty job" made by Gareth, the solution of this puzzle should be really close

Hint 3 (giveaway):

> What really count are the names of the colours (try play with them...)

Comment: Could you provide a text transcription of all the colors? I'm colorblind, and using the color-dropper on each square seems tedious even for people who aren't.

Comment: @Deusovi: sorry, the lack of a text transcription is intentional. By the way the puzzle can be solved by colorblind people too.

Comment: can be solved by colorblind people _without_ a color-picker?

Comment: @Hunter That's surprising. Does that mean that a grey scale image suffices?

Comment: @WhatsUp: no, it means that a colorpicker is necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the extremely helpful 'scutwork' of @GarethMcCaughan, and using Hint #3, the answer is:

> Georgia O'Keeffe:
> "I found I could say things with color and shapes that I couldn't say any other way - things I had no words for."

Explanation:

> Taking the first letter of each color (or each word of the color) gives something like this:
>
> ```
> I    L    GS   N    I    AY   AY   A
> FO   DS   PR   DS   CO   A    T    BB
> EU   A    I    H    EU   N    H    N
> N    Y    DL   AP   L    YO   I    B
> C    T    FF   E    D    T    NG   WO
> I    H    OL   ST   N    H    S    RD
> CO   I    OR   H    T    ER   I    SF
> U    N    G    AT   S    W    H    OR
> ```
>
> You can pretty easily make out some words when read top-to-bottom, left-to-right, like **THAT**, a couple **COULD**s, and then **ANY OTHER WAY THINGS I...WORDS FOR**, which is of course part of her quote:
>
> "I found I could say things with color and shapes that I couldn't say any other way - things I had no words for."

Final lists (Thanks @ChrisCudmore for the last one):

> ```
> I    L    GS   N    I    AY   AY   A
> FO   DS   W    DS   CO   A    T    D
> U    A    I    H    U    N    H    N
> N    Y    T    AP   L    YO   I    O
> D    T    HC   E    D    T    NG   WO
> I    H    OL   ST   N    H    S    RD
> CO   I    OR   H    T    ER   I    SF
> U    N    A    AT   S    W    H    OR
> ```
>
> Irresistible | Lilac | Green Sheen | Nickel | Isabelline | Arylide Yellow | Arylide Yellow | Asparagus
> Fire Opal | Dark Salmon | Wine | Deep Saffron | Carrot Orange | Amethyst | Timberwolf | Drab
> Ultramarine | Avocado | Independence | Heliotrope | Ultramarine | Nickel | Honeydew | Nyanza
> Nickel | Yellow | Taupe | Amaranth Pink | Liberty | Yellow Orange | Icterine | Oxblood
> Desert | Tumbleweed | Hollywood Cerise | Eggshell | Denim | Thistle | Neon Green | Wild Orchid
> Inchworm | Harlequin | Old Lace | Steel Teal | Nyanza | Harlequin | Skobeloff | Rose Dust
> Cadmium Orange | Iris | Old Rose | Honeydew | Tangerine | English Red | Indigo | Spring Frost
> Umber | Nyanza | Ao | Atomic Tangerine | Straw | White | Heliotrope | Orange-Red

Comment: PUCE Red = WINE (same hex code)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Thanks!  Included that on the new list.  Just stuck on one that I can't find a single alternative for, never mind one for the letter I need.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxblood

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Oh man, I even saw that, but they're stated to be different hues so I didn't check color codes.  Actually checking it shows they're exactly the same code!  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**Not really an answer** but (too large to fit in a comment and) may save others some scutwork: OP says that "the lack of a text transcription is intentional" but if this puzzle is mostly about looking up RGB colours on the internet then that is No Fun and I'd like to save other people the bother.

Of course it may turn out that none of this has anything to do with the actual puzzle and I've saved people some *pointless* bother, but actually that's even better.

RGB triples:

> ```
> B3 44 6C  |  C8 A2 C8  |  6E AE A1  |  72 74 72  |  F4 F0 EC  |  E9 D6 6B  |  E9 D6 6B  |  87 A9 6B
> E9 5C 4B  |  E9 96 7A  |  72 2F 37  |  FF 99 33  |  ED 91 21  |  99 66 CC  |  DB D7 D2  |  96 71 17
> 3F 00 FF  |  56 82 03  |  4C 51 6D  |  DF 73 FF  |  3F 00 FF  |  72 74 72  |  F0 FF F0  |  E9 FF DB
> 72 74 72  |  FF FF 00  |  48 3C 32  |  F1 9C BB  |  54 5A A7  |  FF AE 42  |  FC F7 5E  |  80 00 20
> C1 9A 6B  |  DE AA 88  |  F4 00 A1  |  F0 EA D6  |  15 60 BD  |  D8 BF D8  |  39 FF 14  |  D4 70 A2
> B2 EC 5D  |  3F FF 00  |  FD F5 E6  |  5F 8A 8B  |  E9 FF DB  |  3F FF 00  |  00 74 74  |  9E 5E 6F
> ED 87 2D  |  5A 4F CF  |  C0 80 81  |  F0 FF F0  |  F2 85 00  |  AB 4B 52  |  4B 00 82  |  87 FF 2A
> 63 51 47  |  E9 FF DB  |  00 80 00  |  FF 99 66  |  E4 D9 6F  |  FF FF FF  |  DF 73 FF  |  FF 68 1F
> ```

Names, according to Some Website Or Other:

> Irresistible | Lilac | Green Sheen | Nickel | Isabelline | Arylide yellow | Arylide yellow | Asparagus
> Fire opal | Darksalmon | Puce red | Deep saffron | Carrot orange | Amethyst | Timberwolf | Bistre brown
> Electric ultramarine | Avocado | Independence | Heliotrope | Electric ultramarine | Nickel | Honeydew | Nyanza
> Nickel | Yellow | Dark lava | Amaranth pink | Liberty | Yellow Orange | Icterine | Burgundy
> Camel | Tumbleweed | Fashion fuchsia | Eggshell | Denim | Thistle | Neon green | Wild orchid
> Inchworm | Harlequin | Oldlace | Steel Teal | Nyanza | Harlequin | Skobeloff | Rose Dust
> Cadmium orange | Iris | Old rose | Honeydew | Tangerine | English red | Indigo | Spring Frost
> Umber | Nyanza | Green | Atomic tangerine | Straw | White | Heliotrope | Orange-red

Nothing leaps out at me on looking at any of the above, but I haven't looked very hard.

Comment: Your bother is not pointless (and I'm sorry that this puzzle is much bother than fun, I thought it was a well constructed one...)

Comment: I'm not saying it's more bother than fun! I'm just saying that if this is the first step then there's not much fun to _that_. (I got a computer to do it.) Figuring out how to get from this to an actual answer may well be fun.

Comment: I hereby vow to use the word 'scutwork' in everyday conversation as often as possible from this day forwards...!